# Maximum webJobs allowed in Azure under a web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

how many webjobs we can be able to create under a web app in azure? And Maximum size of each web job.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Docs says:

> There is no predefined limit on the number of WebJobs that can run in an App Service instance, but there are practical limits that depend on what the application code is trying to do.

But Azure has a limit of Scheduler that is required for scheduled WebJobs:

> The default max jobs quota is 5 jobs in a free job collection and 50 jobs in a standard job collection.

You can read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits

Comment: Really? In Hungarian?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits